# WLST identify the Gridlink Datasource

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, wlst

I am a bit knowledgeable in wlst, however, I couldn't find on which property the JDBC datasource type is kept. Can you please help me to identify if a JDBC datasource is a Gridlink or not?

```
datasources=cmo.getJDBCSystemResources()
for datasource in datasources:
     dsName=datasource.getName()
      <code here>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got: cmo.getJDBCSystemResources() which will return you array of JDBCSystemResourceMBean.
Each **JDBCSystemResourceMBean** has **JDBCDataSourceBean** which can be retrieve by invoking: **getJDBCResource()**, this method will return you: [JDBCDataSourceBean](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/j2ee/descriptor/wl/JDBCDataSourceBean.html) via which you can receive **JDBCOracleParamsBean** which has method: **isActiveGridLink()**,

> Indicates a configured Active GridLink datasource.

So your code should be something like:

```
    datasources=cmo.getJDBCSystemResources()
    for datasource in datasources:
        datasourceOracleParams = datasource.getJDBCResource().getJDBCOracleParams();
        if datasource.isActiveGridLink():
             print datasource.getName()+" is GridLink";
        else:
             print datasource.getName()+" is not GridLink";
```